# I want to reference one object inside another that references the first object. What problems could this cause?

Tags: java, android, redundancy

I want to be able to see the class of any student when I access it, and I also want to be able to have the list of students when I access a class.

Example:

```
public class ClassRoom {
public String nome;
public List<Student> students;
public ClassRoom(String nome){
    this.nome=nome;
}}
```

and

```
public class Student {
public String nome;
public ClassRoom aClass;
public Student(String nome, ClassRoom aClass){
    this.nome = nome;
    this.aClass = aClass;
}}
```

and

```
public School(){
    ClassRoom c1 = new ClassRoom("English 102");
    Student s1 = new Student("Anna White", c1);
    Student s2 = new Student("Beatrix Blue", c1);
    Student s3 = new Student("Carlos Brown", c1);
    Student s4 = new Student("Dayana Green", c1);
    Student s5 = new Student("Elliot Red", c1);
    Student s6 = new Student("Jefferson Pink", c1);

    c1.students = new ArrayList<>();
    c1.students.add(s1);
    c1.students.add(s2);
    c1.students.add(s3);
    c1.students.add(s4);
    c1.students.add(s5);
    c1.students.add(s6);

    //example
    System.out.println(
            c1.students.get(1).aClass.students.get(2).aClass.students.get(3).nome
    );

}}
```

Is it wrong to program this way? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Cross referencing object of different class in each other creates circular dependency which should be avoided as far as practicable.

There are a lot of demerits of creating circular dependency such as long compile time, low modularity, high coupling, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The only real negative is that you need to keep the data in sync-  if you remove student 1 from classroom A, you also need to remove classroom A from student 1 or your data is inconsistent.

I'd actually recommend a third class used to keep this data in sync, so a single call is the right place to change both classes.  If you do it that way, it may not even be best to store the relationship in the second class, but to store it externally-  for example you may decide its best for to have a Multimap of classrooms to students held in that third class, rather than holding the data directly